Polars: How to map records one to one in a dataframe? Any way to enforce 1:1 mapping in dataframes join operation?
TLDR: I need to map duplicated rows 1:1 within a dataframe. Is there any way to make join operation result in 1:1 mapping (enforce 'validate' parameter)?:
Example:
schema = {
    "id": pl.Utf8,
    "partition_number": pl.Utf8,
    "type": pl.Utf8,
    "state": pl.Int64,
    "price": pl.Float64,
    "quantity": pl.Int64,
    "source": pl.Int64,
    "some_other_random_column": pl.Int64,
}

df = pl.read_csv("data.csv", schema=schema)

source1 = df.filter(pl.col('source') == 1)
source2 = df.filter(pl.col('source') == 2)

overlap = source1.join(source2, on=['partition_number', 'type', 'state', 'price', 
    'quantity'], how='inner', suffix='_other')

If there are duplicated rows in either of these, it will result in one_to_many / many_to_many mapping. So for example shapes (50,7) and (55,7) can result in (78,7) dataframe after join. I want it to be always (50,7) at best. Then I can check which rows are not present in the other dataframe by doing (but I don't need to):
all_rows= source1.join(source2, on=['partition_number', 'type', 'state', 'price',
   'quantity'], how='full', suffix='_other')
only_in_source1 = all_rows.filter(pl.col('quantity_other').is_null()) # (0,7)
only_in_source2 = all_rows.filter(pl.col('quantity').is_null())  # (5,7)


I think in theory by doing the second code block I can calculate how many unique 1:1 mappings there are, but I want them to be mapped not just know the number, regardless of the order. I can then assign them a "mapped_id" value.
It doesn't have to be done this way, I thought similar approach could probably be the fastest, but any suggestion that will help me map rows 1:1 in an optimized way will be great.
EDIT: Added input example and also added 'id' column to schema, sorry I forgot to put it there at start.
Exmaple Input:
id,partition_number,type,state,price,quantity,source,some_other_random_column
s1_1,p1,A,1,100.0,10,1,1001
s1_2,p1,A,1,100.0,10,1,1001
s1_3,p2,B,2,150.0,20,1,1002
s1_4,p3,C,1,200.0,30,1,1003
s2_1,p1,A,1,100.0,10,2,1004
s2_2,p1,A,1,100.0,10,2,1004
s2_3,p1,A,1,100.0,10,2,1004
s2_4,p2,B,2,150.0,20,2,1005
s2_5,p4,D,1,250.0,40,2,1006

And example output:
shape: (3, 9)
┌──────┬──────────────────┬──────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┬────────┬──────────────────┬──────────┐
│ id   ┆ partition_number ┆ type ┆ state ┆ price ┆ quantity ┆ source ┆ some_other_rando ┆ id_other │
│ ---  ┆ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ m_column         ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str              ┆ str  ┆ i64   ┆ f64   ┆ i64      ┆ i64    ┆ ---              ┆ str      │
│      ┆                  ┆      ┆       ┆       ┆          ┆        ┆ i64              ┆          │
╞══════╪══════════════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╪════════╪══════════════════╪══════════╡
│ s1_1 ┆ p1               ┆ A    ┆ 1     ┆ 100.0 ┆ 10       ┆ 1      ┆ 1001             ┆ s2_1     │
│ s1_2 ┆ p1               ┆ A    ┆ 1     ┆ 100.0 ┆ 10       ┆ 1      ┆ 1001             ┆ s2_2     │
│ s1_3 ┆ p2               ┆ B    ┆ 2     ┆ 150.0 ┆ 20       ┆ 1      ┆ 1002             ┆ s2_4     │
└──────┴──────────────────┴──────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┴────────┴──────────────────┴──────────┘

Or even shorter is sufficient (but this can be just filtered from the output above):
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────────┐
│ id   ┆ id_other │
│ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ str  ┆ str      │
╞══════╪══════════╡
│ s1_1 ┆ s2_1     │
│ s1_2 ┆ s2_2     │
│ s1_3 ┆ s2_4     │
└──────┴──────────┘


Not sure if I'm following correctly, but: If you add a "row number" per group, can you find the pairs using group_by? e.g. by = ['partition_number', 'type', 'state', 'price', 'quantity']; df.group_by(*by, pl.int_range(pl.len()).over(by + ['source'])).all()

@jqurious this is brilliant, thank you.
If you don't mind a follow-up question: If dataframe consisted of say, 10000 rows with many different partitions, would it make sense optimization-wise to filter the dataframe into smaller frames and then add the row numbers? In order to avoid the group_by having to search through a lot of rows that will not match anyway? So I could create smaller frames by filtering by partition_number, type, state and then add row numbers to group_by price and quantity only within the filtered group? 1/2

2/2 That should limit the amount of rows that I know won't match in group_by anyway? But maybe by performing all at once, polars will optimize it better by itself and pararellize it then if I create smaller dataframes in for loops like for partition in df["partition_number"].unique(): df.filter(pl.col("parition_number") == partition

I'd imagine letting Polars do it all at once would be much faster. You could do df.filter(pl.struct(*by, pl.int_range(pl.len()).over(by + ['source'])).is_duplicated()) - but I'm not sure if that would make a difference - you'd have to benchmark it.

One way to go around solving is you can use a unique identifier for each row before performing the join. This way ensures that each row in the first dataframe has a corresponding unique row in the second dataframe, maintaining a one-to-one relationship. This can all be done with some very simple steps:

Add a unique identifier to each row in both dataframes using the with_row_index method (Polars Documentation - with_row_index)
Perform the join operation using the unique identifier along with the existing join keys (Polars Documentation - join)
Ensure one-to-one mapping by selecting unique rows using the unique method (Polars Documentation - unique)

Using your example:
import polars as pl

schema = {
    "partition_number": pl.Utf8,
    "type": pl.Utf8,
    "state": pl.Int64,
    "price": pl.Float64,
    "quantity": pl.Int64,
    "source": pl.Int64,
    "some_other_random_column": pl.Int64,
}

df = pl.read_csv("data.csv", schema=schema)

source1 = df.filter(pl.col("source") == 1).with_row_index(
    name="row_id" # add row_id to ensure one-to-one mapping
)
source2 = df.filter(pl.col("source") == 2).with_row_index(name="row_id")

# Perform the join operation based on the unique identifier and existing join keys
joined = source1.join(
    source2,
    on=['partition_number', 'type', 'state', 'price', 'quantity', 'row_id'], # added row_id to join keys
    how='inner',
    suffix='_other',
)

# Ensure one-to-one mapping by selecting unique rows
unique_joined = joined.unique(
    subset=["partition_number", "type", "state", "price", "quantity", "row_id"]
)

print(unique_joined)

example data (data.csv):
partition_number,type,state,price,quantity,source,some_other_random_column
p1,A,1,100.0,10,1,1001
p2,B,2,150.0,20,1,1002
p3,C,1,200.0,30,1,1003
p1,A,1,100.0,10,2,1004
p2,B,2,150.0,20,2,1005
p4,D,1,250.0,40,2,1006

Result:
shape: (2, 10)
┌────────┬──────────────────┬──────┬───────┬───┬────────┬──────────────────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ row_id ┆ partition_number ┆ type ┆ state ┆ … ┆ source ┆ some_other_random_column ┆ source_other ┆ some_other_random_column_other │
│ ---    ┆ ---              ┆ ---  ┆ ---   ┆   ┆ ---    ┆ ---                      ┆ ---          ┆ ---                            │
│ u32    ┆ str              ┆ str  ┆ i64   ┆   ┆ i64    ┆ i64                      ┆ i64          ┆ i64                            │
╞════════╪══════════════════╪══════╪═══════╪═══╪════════╪══════════════════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ p1               ┆ A    ┆ 1     ┆ … ┆ 1      ┆ 1001                     ┆ 2            ┆ 1004                           │
│ 1      ┆ p2               ┆ B    ┆ 2     ┆ … ┆ 1      ┆ 1002                     ┆ 2            ┆ 1005                           │
└────────┴──────────────────┴──────┴───────┴───┴────────┴──────────────────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘


Thank you for answering. I have an 'id' column that I forgot to put in. Edited it in now. As well as expected input and output. Your approach is a cool, but it unfortunately doesn't work if the rows are in different order or  the number of rows for sources differs.

It sounds like you are after a semi-join.
See the Polars user guide for an example.

The semi join returns all rows from the left frame in which the join key is also present in the right frame.

It only keeps number of rows the same or reduces them. In effect, it only does a 1:1 join, never a 1:many or many:many. This sounds like what you want.
If not, please provide an example input with expected output (i.e., a reduced version of the contents of data.csv)
Edit based on additional information
Given you need information from both tables, the simplest thing you can do is ensure your right table source2 only has one row per combination of join keys. Then you will know the join is 1:1. As you stated in your comment, the id_other can be any arbitrary match, but only 1 match.
join_keys = ['partition_number', 'type', 'state', 'price', 'quantity']

source1.join(
    # Only keep 1 row per join key
    # The default behaviour is an arbitrary choice,
    # but this can be controlled via a parameter
    source2.unique(join_keys),
    on=join_keys,
    how='inner',
    suffix='_other',
)


Thank you for answering. The semi-join would work but it returns only the left table -> I don't know the resulting mapping. I forgot to put 'id' column into schema (I apologize, edited it in now). I also added the expected input and output. I need to have the id to id mapping as a result of the join operation. If there is a way to modify the semi join so that it adds the mapped id as "id_other" then that could work, don't know if that's possible,

Thank you for the additional detail. Based on your example input s1_1 and s1_2 joins to all of s2_1 and s2_2 and s2_3. In your example output, how would it know to match s1_1 with s2_1 and not pick s2_3 as the matching id instead? Or are you after an arbitrary id_other?

It can be arbitrary, just has to match one to one. In the future there might be a 'created_at_time" column and I will then try to map records based on the smallest time delta between them, but for now it can choose arbitrary.

@barrelquentin997, I have updated my answer with a solution

Thank you. Using unique won't work when the amount of identical rows differs between tables. For example if we were to delete s2_1 and s2_2 from the example, s1_1 and s1_2 will both map to s2_3. And by calling unique, it will always map to arbitrary chosen single row, not to arbitrary chosen duplicated rows but with distinct id.
